# I have a question regarding the use of dummy variables in a proof.

Tags: proof-writing

Lets look at the following question.  Why would the proof be incorrect?

Let U be any set.  Prove that there exists an $A \in \mathcal{P}(U)$ such that for every $B \in \mathcal{P}(U)$, $A \cap B = B$.

Proof.  Our goal is $\exists A \in \mathcal{P}(U) \forall B \in \mathcal{P}(U)(A \cap B = B)$.  We choose $A = B$.  Clearly $B \cap B = B$.

I'm quite certain that the correct answer is Let A = U.  What I'm struggling with is explaining why we can't Let A = B.  Or is it fine to choose A = B?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it says for *every* B.  If you say A = B, then A is actually changing with every chosen B, so you aren't referring to a specific A.

Comment: I've thought about that as well but then lets take a look at another proof.            
Prove that there exist a real number x such that for every real number y, $y^2x = y-x$.  

Our goal would be $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R}(y^2x = y-x)$.  The answer would be to choose $x = \frac{y}{y^2+1}$   

In this case x is also changing with every chosen y.  Is it because x is more specific in this case?

Comment: I think the example you give is faulty.  Can you show where this is done?  I can see how someone might say "prove that for every real number y there exists an x such that $y^2x = y - x$."  In that case the result would be correct.  But as you have written it, There is no real number $x$ that satisfies $y^2x = y - x$ for every real number $y$.

Comment: You are correct.  I mixed up 2 questions from section 3.6 of the book "How to prove it".  It should be as you described "prove that for every real number y there exists an unique x such that...".  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you want to show $$\exists A \in \mathcal{P}(U) \, \forall B \in \mathcal{P}(U)(A \cap B = B).$$

It might help to say this in words: Prove there exists an $A \in \mathcal{P}(U)$ *such that* for all $B \in \mathcal{P}(U)$ we have $A \cap B = B$.

The clause "for all $B \in \mathcal{P}(U)$ we have $A \cap B = B$" is a *property* that you want $A$ to have.  Your goal is to choose an $A$ so that this clause is true.  Thus your proof must begin

Let $A = $ __.  Then, for all $B \in \mathcal{P}(U)$, we have $A \cap B = \ldots$ (fill in blanks) $ \ldots = B$.

The variable $B$, then, should not be introduced until you have already defined what $A$ is, so that the clause is true for *all* $B$.

Comment: Thanks for making it so clear.  I was confused at first since I thought there was a counter argument but then as johnnyb pointed out, that counter argument was faulty.  I simply misread a question that had a solution for it in the Appendix section.